# Recursion in Array SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, recursion, sas

I have an existing collection of variables a_0,...,a_45 where a_i represents the amount of stuff I have on day i. I'd like to create a new collection of variables b_0,...,b_45 to represent the incremental change in stuff I have on day i (i.e. b_k=a_k-a_(k-1) ). My approach:

```
data test;
    set dataset;
    array a a_0-a_45;
    array b b_0-b_45;
    b(1)=a(1);
    do i=2 to 45;
        b(i)=a(i)-a(i-1);
    end;
run;
```

However my b variables just come out missing.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and full code so we can replicate the issue? At this point in time it's not clear what you want or what's not working as expected. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Your code is fine. You need to show example data where it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you modeling the data in this way?  Why not have 46 rows with two variable DAY and A where DAY goes from 0 to 45?

Comment: I don't see any recursion -- did you mean iteration ?

Comment: The array has 46 elements.  The loop should be `2 to 46`.  That may or may not contribute to your problem.  In general use `... to DIM(array)` to iterate to the last element of a typical, 1-dimensional, array.  If the array statement defines the index bounds you should use `LBOUND(array) to HBOUND(array)` to iterate from lower to upper index bounds.  For multi-dimensional (or n-dimensional) arrays the syntax is `LBOUND(array-name,dimension-n)`

Answer (score 0):

What initial values do you have for `a_1` to `a_45` before you start the loop? As you are not intialising them (except for `a_0` ≡ `a(1)`), every `b(i)` term will be a difference of 2 `a` terms, of which at least one will be missing, unless these variables are populated in your input dataset.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. My a variables already exist and have values. I want to create b values based off these existing a values

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code showing that the delta computation is correct when the variable names in the data set align with the variables named in the array statement in the data step.

Sample data

```
data have(keep=product_id note a_:);
  do product_id = 1 to 100;
    length note $15;
    array amount a_0-a_45;
    call missing(of amount(*));

    if (ranuni(123) < 0.5) then do;
      note = 'static deltas';
      static_delta = ceil(5 * ranuni(123));
      amount(1) = static_delta;
      do inventory_day = 2 to dim(amount);
        amount(inventory_day) = amount(inventory_day-1) + static_delta;
      end;
    end;

    else do;
      note = 'random deltas';
      amount(1) = ceil(5 * ranuni(123));
      do inventory_day = 2 to dim(amount);
        amount(inventory_day) = max ( 0, amount(inventory_day-1) + floor(10 * ranuni(123)) - 5 );
      end;    
    end;

    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

Compute deltas

```
data want;
  set have;
  array amount a_0-a_45;
  array delta  b_0-b_45;

  delta(1) = amount(1);
  do i=2 to dim(amount);
    delta(i) = amount(i) - amount(i-1);
  end;

  drop i;
  format a_: b_: 4.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Richard has already suggested in his comment while I was working on writing the code...Basically the only error that you have in your code is that your code should loop from 2 to 46 because there are 46 elements in the array. below code should work for you.

```
%macro f();                                                                                                                             
 data dataset;                                                                                                                          
   %do i = 0 %to 45;                                                                                                                    
   a_&i. = ranuni(2);                                                                                                                   
   %end;                                                                                                                                
 run;                                                                                                                                   
%mend;                                                                                                                                  


%f();                                                                                                                                   

data test;                                                                                                                              
     set dataset;                                                                                                                       
     array a1 a_0-a_45;                                                                                                                 
     array b1 b_0-b_45;                                                                                                                 
     /* This line will help in avoiding b_0 to have a missing value */                                                                  
     b1(1)=a1(1);                                                                                                                       
     do i=2 to 46;                                                                                                                      
         b1(i)=a1(i)-a1(i-1);                                                                                                           
     end;                                                                                                                               
 run;
```